# How can I send data from HDFS through Django backend to Angular 5 frontend?

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework, angular5

I am downloading file from Hadoop to Django backend and storing the file using the code below:

```
import shutil
import requests

url = 'http://112.138.0.12:9870/webhdfs/v1/user/username/1.jpg?op=OPEN&user.name=username'
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('img.png', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
del response
```

I don't need to store the file in backend local system since I want to send this file to Angular 5 frontend where user will save this file in their local system. I'm getting the following error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte.

Can someone suggest me what would be the right way to do download large files in a short time?

**DJANGO:**

views.py:

```
class DownloadFileView(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = UserNameSerializer

    def get(self, request):

        key = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION').split()[1]

        user_id = Token.objects.get(key=key).user_id

        user_name = User.objects.get(id=user_id).username

        response = download_files(user_name)

        return Response(response)

def download_files(user_name):

    response = requests.get('http://112.138.0.12:9870/webhdfs/v1/user/' + user_name + '/1.jpg?op=OPEN&user.name=username', stream=True)

    return response.raw
```

**ANGULAR:**

```
  DownloadFile(){


this.userService.DownloadFiles().subscribe((data : any) => {

  const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream'});

  fileUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));

}

}



DownloadFiles() {

    this.token = localStorage.getItem('userToken')

    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Authorization': 'token ' + this.token });
    console.log(reqHeader)
    return this.http.get(this.rootURL + 'download/', { headers: reqHeader});

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with your unicode error, it's because:

> HttpResponse.**init**(content='', content_type=None, status=200,
>   reason=None, charset=None)
>   Instantiates an HttpResponse
>   object with the given page content and content type.
>
> content should be an iterator or a string. If it’s an iterator, it
>   should return strings, and those strings will be joined together to
>   form the content of the response. If it is not an iterator or a
>   string, it will be converted to a string when accessed.

I do believe django is having trouble converting the binary data in the file to string. A more common approach when dealing with file downloads is:

```
 response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/jpeg")
 response.write(binary_data)
```

This works because there is a call to make_bytes behind the scenes which handles the binary data correctly.

Having said that, this is not the most efficient way to go about it. Your web app makes a request to a remote server using requests, and then passes that onto the client. Why not get your angular code to fetch the data directly from the end point?

Can't do that because you want authentication you say? Ok, How about checking the authentiation and then sending an HttpResponseDirect like this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('http://112.138.0.12:9870/webhdfs/v1/user/' + user_name + '/1.jpg?op=OPEN&user.name=username')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I still have a problem with connection with webhdfs described in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919856/angular-5-hadoop-webhdfs-error-xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed. Any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: I forgot about this question. `HttpResponseRedirect`  was what I was looking for and I didn't know about its existence before. Obviously I accept the answer. Thanks for the help.